# Piping email to PHP - Missing actual email address

Tags: php, email, pipe

I have an email address that pipes all messages to a PHP script. I know how to parse the contents, but I can't find an actual email addresses anywhere in the "to" and "from" headers. Is that something that just isn't available?

So what I'm receiving looks something like this:

```
To: Jane Doe, John Doe 
Subject: This is the subject.
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2012 17:07:25 -0500
From: Test User 
Message-ID: 
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I only get the names, but not the email addresses. Does anybody have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure they're not there? Addresses tend to be enclosed in `< >` brackets, which would vanish if you're viewing this in a browser. If you are viewing in a browser, try viewing the page's source, in case those bracketed addresses are being interpreted as html tags.

Comment: You are right. I'm surprised I couldn't see it with `print_r` function and the `<pre>` tag, and "view source" was a no go as well, but now I'm just writing it to a text file and it's there indeed.